# Upload mobile app to cloud instead of google play or app store

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

Can we store our app in cloud instead of storing it in google play or app store for client to download? If yes we service is there for this in azure and aws? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Stack Overflow != Google Search

Comment: Thank you, I did search but i didnt get answer that answer my query.

Comment: @LamaMadan Is there any update on my answer below? If you find my answer is useful, pls upvote/accept it. So that it can help other community members

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/)

This way you can manage the end-to-end lifecycle for a mobile application. Services like Build, Test, Distribute, Diagnostics, Analytics, Push Notifications etc., all can be done in a single place.

*Users can install the app via email distribution lists for testing, much as they'd download an app from the app store*

[For Pricing refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/pricing)